# Sencha Touch 2.1: How to create/destroy tab content to increase performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I've got a TabPanel in my ViewPort with 4 tabs; is it possible to keep the tabs itself (the 'buttons' to tap), but remove/create the content/the dom if not visible?

I'm looking for something like tab.removeContent() and tab.createContent(), I guess...

I tried:

```
activeitemchange: function(component, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
    Ext.Viewport.remove(oldValue, true);
}
```

which seems to do nothing...

This removes everything:

```
activeitemchange: function(component, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
    Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);
}
```

I got the remove-part working:

```
oldValue.removeInnerAt(0);
```

but what's the 'opposite' of that, i.e. how can I set the tab's content?

```
var myContent = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyView');
// and now?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548164/how-to-destroy-an-inactive-view-in-sencha-touch does this help?

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Senior Forum Manager Mitchell Simoens made a extension for this. It can be found on his github page: [Optimized tab (git)](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.tab.OptimizedTab)

The tabs will be removed and cached.

**EDIT:**
In your current situation you're extending `Ux.tab.OptimizedTab`, which is wrong. The lib only does some changes to some of the methods of `Ext.tab.Panel` (the lib doesn't extend `Ext.tab.Panel` either. In the example given by Mitchell you can see he is extending the `Ext.tab.Panel` and settings the defaultType on `optimized-tab`.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype  : 'main',

    requires : [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ux.tab.OptimizedTab'
    ],

    config: {
        tabBarPosition : 'bottom',
        defaultType    : 'optimized-tab',
        items : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you changed the lib classname which, in my opinion, is a lack of respect and above all you have given it a wrong name and placed it in the wrong folder. (The name you gave is `Crossfit.view.OptimizedTab` but it isn't a view at all..)

I would like to give you some compliments on your good architecture of the app,I haven't seen many people who understand Sencha Touch architecture. But you, Mitchell and I are some of them :)

Comment: ooookay, looks great - are there any example how to use it, i.e. how to include that extension into my app?

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is a demo app on the github root page which you can run and search for clues on how to use it. (The code is in the app/view/Main.js file). You will have to set the `defaultType: 'optimized-tab'` config on the tabpanel.

Comment: I don't get it... my element extends the optimized tab element, but I always get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined` in the optimized tabs constructor... the parameter is undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: I uploaded the code to github; you find the file in question here: https://github.com/haemi/Crossfit/blob/master/mobile/app/view/ViewPort.js

Comment: @swalkner updated my answer to include your error (i think) :P

Comment: thank you very much - I didn't mean to lack respect, not at all... I just didn't (don't) understand it 100%... so your compliment was nice but not completely deserved ;) please see my updated github-repo; I don't get an error any more, but the methods in optimizedtab aren't called either... when I download the example from Mitchell, everything works as expected. Could you have a look at it again, please? https://github.com/haemi/CrossfitSencha/blob/master/app/view/ViewPort.js

Comment: Sure, I will tomorrow. (And I understand, I didn't mean to insult you or anything.)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems using this component originally, the key here you'll notice is that if you have 3 items in your tabpanel, each item must have the xtype 'optimized-tab', and inside them you have your actual items.

For example:

```
items: [
        {
            xtype: 'optimized-tab',
            title: 'Tab 1',
            iconCls: 'info',
            baseCls: 'myBtn',
            cls: 'myBtn',
            html: 'Tab 1',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'component',
                    baseCls: 'myBtn',
                    cls: 'myBtn',
                    ui: 'light'
                }
            ]
        },
```

To test that it is actually working, paste this in your console to find the amount of DOM items:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").length
```

If your first tab is empty you should see around 50 items, if you have a map you should be around 200 etc. If the optimized tab is not working you will probably see around 400 items in your DOM.

If it is working, you may see the optimized tab removing the items prematurely before the animation is complete. So you can modify it slightly to remove items after.

You can also refer to this link for more information: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-207907.html?s=24386d2ced82d0625b8199247e0f5c64

:-)